# Finding Non Entries within another data table (MS Access SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I know there ust be a few hundred of this similar post, but I have tried all the other ways in MS Access and still cannot get it to work.

So my working code is as follows

```
SELECT FVR.*, V.[Week Commencing], F.Date, V.Date
FROM FVR 
INNER JOIN (F 
INNER JOIN V ON (F.[Week Commencing] = V.[Week Commencing]) AND (F.GUID = V.GUID))
              ON (FVR.GUID = V.GUID) AND (FVR.GUID = F.GUID)
```

My desired effect would be to show the Dates of the "F" table that have no entries in the "V"Table.

Sorry for being crpytic on the tables but it is for work. I thoght i had a good idead on how to do most of this.

any help would be amazing as I have been pulling my hair over this for a while now.

Cheers and thanks in advance.

Editing this to add in the full code as it will make more sense.

I basically have am unable to produce the Data range from F(Forecast) that Does not match in V(Visits) am trying to bring up a list of forecasted dates that have not been visited using the Week Commencing and GUID from both tables, The FVR table is just a table that holds the regional data matching up to the GUID. @Hogan I tried your way and ended up with syntax errors, I almost got somewhere and then lost it again. I thought I had a bit more knowledge of SQL than this.

Full code is as follows

```
    SELECT  FVR.*, [Visits].[Week Commencing], [Forecast].[Forecast Date], [Visits].Date
    FROM ForecastVisitRegion 
    INNER JOIN ([Forecast] INNER JOIN [Visits] ON ([Forecast].[Week Commencing] = [Visits].[Week Commencing])
    AND ([Forecast].GUID = [Visits].GUID)) ON (FVR.GUID = [Visits].GUID)
    AND (FVR.GUID = [External - Forecast].GUID)
```

Thanks again

Stephen Edwards

Answer (score 0):

You need to use left joins:

```
SELECT FVR.*, V.[Week Commencing], NZ(V.Date,F.Date) as virtual_date
FROM FVR 
LEFT JOIN F ON FVR.GUID = F.GUID
LEFT JOIN V ON FVR.GUID = V.GUID F.[Week Commencing] = V.[Week Commencing]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand why `FVR` is coming into the mix but you need a `left Join`.

```
Select F.*
from F
left join V on F.[Week Commencing] = V.[Week Commencing] AND F.GUID = V.GUID
where V.GUID is null
```

The left join ensures all the records (matched or not) from `F` are included in the result set. Then the where `V.GUID is null` removes the records where no match was found in `V` leaving you with the `F` records with no match.

Another approach would be to use the `NOT EXISTS` statement in the `WHERE` Clause

```
Select F.*
from F
where not exists (select * from V where F.[Week Commencing] = V.[Week Commencing] AND F.GUID = V.GUID)
```

Comment: you are showing how to filter on existence -- he wants to show one or the other as he said in the question "show the Dates of the "F" table that have no entries in the "V"Table."

Comment: @Hogan I'm not sure I understand the difference. This is showing records in F that are not in V. Doing just a left join will show that but will also show all the records where a data in F is also in V.

Comment: Look at my answer -- the user wants a query that shows V.Date when it exists and F.Date when it doesn't -- eg F table contains the default data.  This is a common pattern in Access you use NZ and in SQL you use COALESCE()

Comment: @Hogan I see, I guess I don't read the question that way. It didn't say `show the Dates of the "F" table when there are no entries in the "V"Table`  We'll see what OP says

Comment: I see what you mean -- I just assumed he wanted to do what everyone always wants to do.  But this could be the exception that proves the rule.

Comment: Hi Guy's I think I have over confused it here, I usually do this.